# Transforming sibling lists into 1 main list (XML to XML)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML to XML transformation to write. My input XML document contains a number of sibling lists (with child lists) that I want to transform into 1 main list (without getting rid of the child lists). In other words, I want to suppress each sibling list after the first one, but retain all children lists.

Here is a sample input XML document:

```
<back>
<index id="subject">
    <title>Subject Index</title>
    <index id="section">
        <list id="index">
            <item>apple</item>
            <item>almond</item>
            <item>american cheese</item>
            <item>Avocado 
                <list id="index">
                    <item>Mexican</item>
                    <item>Chilian</item>
                </list>
            </item>
            <item>asparagus</item>
            <item>anchovie</item>
        </list>
    </index>
    <index id="section">
        <list id="index">
            <item>banana</item>
            <item>barley</item>
            <item>bagel 
                <list id="index">
                    <item>sesame</item>
                    <item>plain</item>
                    <item>everything</item>
                </list>
            </item>
            <list id="index">
                <item>bean 
                    <list id="index">
                        <item>green bean</item>
                        <item>navy bean</item>
                    </list>
                </item>
            </list>
        </list>
    </index>
</index>
```

And I want to transform the above into the below structure, with one main list id="index". List children should remain, but sibling lists should be suppressed.

```
<back>
<index id="subject">
    <title>Subject Index</title>
        <list id="index">
            <item>apple</item>
            <item>almond</item>
            <item>american cheese</item>
            <item>Avocado 
                <list id="index">
                    <item>Mexican</item>
                    <item>Chilian</item>
                </list>
            </item>
            <item>asparagus</item>
            <item>anchovie</item>
            <item>banana</item>
            <item>barley</item>
            <item>bagel
            <list id="index">
                <item>sesame</item>
                <item>plain</item>
                <item>everything</item>
            </list>
            </item>
            <list id="index">
                <item>bean 
                    <list id="index">
                        <item>green bean</item>
                        <item>navy bean</item>
                    </list>
                </item>
            </list>
         </list>
</index>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="index[1]/list[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*| ../../index/list/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="index/index"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/*/*/index[position() >1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<back>
    <index id="subject">
        <title>Subject Index</title>
        <index id="section">
            <list id="index">
                <item>apple</item>
                <item>almond</item>
                <item>american cheese</item>
                <item>Avocado
                    <list id="index">
                        <item>Mexican</item>
                        <item>Chilian</item>
                    </list></item>
                <item>asparagus</item>
                <item>anchovie</item>
            </list>
        </index>
        <index id="section">
            <list id="index">
                <item>banana</item>
                <item>barley</item>
                <item>bagel
                    <list id="index">
                        <item>sesame</item>
                        <item>plain</item>
                        <item>everything</item>
                    </list></item>
                <list id="index">
                    <item>bean
                        <list id="index">
                            <item>green bean</item>
                            <item>navy bean</item>
                        </list></item>
                </list>
            </list>
        </index>
    </index>
</back>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<back>
   <index id="subject">
      <title>Subject Index</title>
      <list id="index">
         <item>apple</item>
         <item>almond</item>
         <item>american cheese</item>
         <item>Avocado
                    <list id="index">
               <item>Mexican</item>
               <item>Chilian</item>
            </list>
         </item>
         <item>asparagus</item>
         <item>anchovie</item>
         <item>banana</item>
         <item>barley</item>
         <item>bagel
                    <list id="index">
               <item>sesame</item>
               <item>plain</item>
               <item>everything</item>
            </list>
         </item>
         <list id="index">
            <item>bean
                        <list id="index">
                  <item>green bean</item>
                  <item>navy bean</item>
               </list>
            </item>
         </list>
      </list>
   </index>
</back>
```

Comment: Thanks very much Dimitre. This was taking me two days to think about...noobie.